# MonoDevelop -- GTK Designer just shows a blank square?

Tags: ide, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I am having problems getting the GTK designer to work with MonoDevelop. I tried 2.4 on Arch Linux and it gave this problem. Then I tried 2.2 on OpenBSD and it gives the exact same problem. Both machines are 64bit.

Instead of having a window to drag things on I just have a blank square:

[alt text http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/4766/monodevelop.png](http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/4766/monodevelop.png)

The [tutorials I've seen](https://www.monodevelop.com/Stetic_GUI_Designer/) look similar to this though:

[image]
<sub>(source: [monodevelop.com](http://monodevelop.com/@api/deki/files/142/=Stetic_Tutorial_06.jpg?size=bestfit&width=700&height=425))</sub>

So what gives? With my blank square I can't drag anything onto it, not a VBox or other container even. It will not react to anything.

Am I missing some sort of GTK# configuration or what? I find it highly improbable that both OSs' packages I tried are broken. Also, I've attached a (huge) bounty to this because this is a pretty big issue for me.

The console output from the starting of Mono and including me trying to drag an  element onto the gray box [is here](https://pastebin.com/2hN9zKeN)

**Update**

Ok, so I've finally gotten a bit closer to solving the mystery. I use Fluxbox as my window manager usually. Well I tried using both KDE and Gnome-Session and both of them cause MonoDevelop to work properly(though still missing the window border, you could at least drag components onto it). Now my question is what makes Fluxbox not work for it?

Comment: Fluxbox is the minority on this one. I can run MonoDevelop under Xephyr in both XFCE and AwesomeWM with no issues. As best as I can tell, Fluxbox interferes with Monodevelop's drag'n'drop.

Comment: Please [edit] the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem in openSUSE 11.3 x64 KDE using Mono JIT compiler version 2.6.7 (tarball Wed Jul 14 18:00:23 UTC 2010) downloaded from [here](http://o-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html)

***type -a monodevelop*** returns:

```
monodevelop is /usr/bin/monodevelop 
monodevelop is /usr/bin/X11/monodevelop
```

Running monodevelop from terminal gives the following [output](http://pastebin.com/cTnfZFvv)

1)

> WARNING: Cannot find Mozilla directory
>   containing libgtkembedmoz.so. Some
>   Addins may not be able to function.
>   Please set MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME to your
>   Mozilla directory.

This can be solved by adding an environment variable in your .bashrc file from your home directory.

> export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME='/path/to/libgtkembedmoz.so/directory/'

To find if that library exists on your systems use:

> sudo find / -name libgtkembedmoz.so
>   -print

(from [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/monodevelop/+bug/212467) bug report this library is contain in the Mozilla's XUL Runner package, but in newer versions I don't know if it's still there, I had to use libgtkembedmoz.so provided by [Slickedit](http://www.slickedit.com/) which was installed in /opt/slickedit/bin/mozilla/)

2)

> WARNING [2010-07-29 20:22:37Z]: Inotify watch limit is too low (8192).

To resolve this problem read [Inotify Watches Limit](http://monodevelop.com/Inotify_Watches_Limit)

3)

> WARNING [2010-07-29 20:22:37Z]: Error creating composed icon gtk-execute___asm0__debug-overlay-22.png__SmallToolbar at size SmallToolbar. Icon __asm0__debug-overlay-22.png__SmallToolbar is 22x22, expected 16x16.

I get the exact same error using Monodevelop 2.4, and I think this could be either from a broken GTK# installation or from a bug in Monodevelop,

Your result is the same as mine, see [here](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2pt2ej6&s=3). I suggest compiling MonoDevelop from [Github](http://github.com/mono/monodevelop) and/or using a newer version of **gtk-sharp/gdk-sharp**

This part

> ERROR [2010-07-29 20:22:37Z]: GdkPixbuf-Critical: gdk_pixbuf_composite: assertion `dest_x >= 0 && dest_x + dest_width <= dest->width' failed

appears in GTK and GDK crashes,

If this does not resolve the problem submitting a [bug report](http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs) is the next option. Although this is somehow strange, since I managed to complete the same tutorial using Kubuntu 10.04 LTS 64 bit a few weeks ago.

Comment: Wow, pretty thorough on all my output. I'll try all of this tonight when I'm home.

Comment: I think that the window border is only drawn if you're using the Metacity window manager and that's why is not drawn. And those errors are harmeless in this respect. I cannot verify this myself right now cause I only use KDE, but this is plausible.

Comment: see the update on my question. Apparently it is something to do with Fluxbox

Comment: Indeed, seems to be a problem either with Fluxbox or something from Mono packages, another guy has the same problem see: http://tinyurl.com/27bdrrj . I don't have window borders in KDE but other than that everything is fine.

Comment: Heh 2 years and this bug is still not fixed at all

Answer (score 2):

Uh, that *is* the designer.  If the toolbox didn't show up, go to View->Pads->Toolbox to bring it up.

Note that this Gtk, you can't just drop a button or textbox on the design surface.  You have to drop a container control first, and then can place buttons and such inside the container.

Comment: Every tutorial I've seen shows a window there instead of a gray box. Plus I've tried dragging a VBox onto it and it does nothing

Comment: The window border may not appear if MD is unable to invoke certain private Metacity APIs, but it shouldn't stop anything from working.

Answer (score 1):

1. set global gtk theme to default
2. check all bindings depends
3. try start monodevelop from console and post output on pastebin

Comment: strange... i have something distro, with latest mono and monodevelop

in arch latest mono packages installed?
composite managers like as compiz disabled?
try run from other user.
i think this is problem missing depends or broken gtk configuration

Comment: I'm running Fluxbox, but I'll try from another user.

Answer (score 0):

"Now my question is what makes Fluxbox not work for it? " remember the GTK protect was made for GNOME project, all the libraries are made to work on that Desktop. so need to see all the dependencies to run it property